# On the Chinese version of the movie "Braveheart"

Tags: translation, culture, movies

I am pretty sure the movie "Braveheart" by Mel Gibson exists in a Chinese language version as there is a [Chinese Wikipedia article](https://zh.wikipedia.org/zh-hans/%E5%8B%87%E6%95%A2%E7%9A%84%E5%BF%83?wprov=sfla1) about this movie.

I would like to know about the official Chinese translation of a part of the famous freedom speech. If there are different Chinese versions for Hong Kong, Taiwan and Mainland China, you can provide the translations of all versions but a single version which is known to you counts as an answer as well.

You can see the relevant passage on [Youtube](https://youtu.be/TME0xubdHQc?si=J3d7s0bpYuB-6d4x) in the very end of the clip. In writing, it reads as:

> ...they may take our lives but they'll never take our freedom!

Comment: 1’36” & 1’38” of this youtube video, is what you’re looking for  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hBw1FDP2HXI

Comment: There are websites that collect subtitles of movies. For example, subtitles of Braveheart are available at: https://www.ddzimu.com/download/index.php?id=1294639

Comment: However, note that most of them do not record the translator, and most of them are not "official" but produced by volunteer communities called 字幕组

Comment: For everyone, the translation in the YouTube video reads as 他们也许能夺走我们的生命，但他们永远夺不走我们的自由! Thank you for the reference.

Comment: @user2249675 I can't open the files on ddzimu on the phone. Maybe, I need a special program for this or to do it on a computer. Anyways, thank you for the reference!

Comment: @ChristophMark They are srt files intended to be used in a video player. You can open it with a text editor. If it shows gibbish, you may also need to set encoding to GB2312 or GB18030.

Comment: @user2249675 I'll try on a computer later and compare the translations. 

Comment: In fact, I'm mostly interested in a version a Chinese native might recognize as a quotation from the movie, that is the most widespread translation.

Comment: @ChristophMark You can check out its Douban page: https://movie.douban.com/subject/1294639/ In particular this comment: https://movie.douban.com/review/8705364/

Comment: @user2249675 The first translation in this comment is more comprehendible for me as a German. I guess I'm happy with this one for my purpose. It also matches the one from YouTube except 但 is replaced with 但是 